# How does apple approve the app that controls external multimedia player without having it?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am just wondering how does apple approve the iPhone app that communicates via WiFi network with external multimedia player device that is controlled by this app?

Actually, this app is remote control for multimedia player such as smart tv

How would I submit this to apple?

Does anyone know how to submit app that controls multimedia player to register app store?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. Kind of a gray teritory here.

We have an app in App Store that acts as a dashboard for boat (gathering data from wifi device).
Since it's wifi it doesn't need (nor can it get) MFi approval (as is probably the case with your device).

App passed the approval process. We did have to submit some additional information about the application. The main issue is: **all functions of the application have to be visible to the reviewers, even if they don't function without the external device**.

How to achieve that depends on you device GUI. You could implement a kind of demo functionality.

Comment: @jeyoon: You're welcome. Hope you're app will pass without problems. :)